# How to pass File object to HTTPX request in FastAPI endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi

The idea is to get file object from one endpoint and send it to other endpoints to work with it without saving it.
Let's have this expample code:

```
import httpx
from fastapi import Request, UploadFile, File


app = FastAPI()
client = httpx.AsyncClient()

@app.post("/endpoint/")
async def foo(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...))
    urls = ["/some/other/endpoint", "/another/endpoint/"]
    for url in urls:
        response = await client.post(url) # here I need to send the file to the other endpoint 
    return {"bar": "baz"}


@app.post("/some/other/endpoint/")
async def baz(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)): # and here to use it
     # Do something with the file object
     return {"file": file.filename}


@app.post("/another/endpoint/")
async def baz(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)): # and here to use it too
     # Do something with the file object
     return {"file": file.content_type}
```

As stated [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/) I tried to do something like this:

```
data = {'file': file}
response = await client.post(url, data=data)
```

But it errored with

```
'{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class \'str\'>","type":"value_error"}]}'
```

Example curl request:

```
curl -X 'POST' -F 'file=@somefile' someserver/endpoint/
```

Comment: maybe you should use `post(..., file=...)` instead of `post(..., data=...)`

Comment: @furas I tried but `AsyncClient.post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'` error shows

Comment: maybe it has to be `files=` with `s` at the end.

Comment: @furas this is the correct answer. Please post it below to get your internet points

Comment: Thanks for the question, I am trying to do the same without any luck.

Comment: Future readers should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`httpx` similar to `requests` uses `files=....` to send files.

ie.

```
post(..., files={'file': file.file}, ...)
```

or with filename

```
post(..., files={'file': (file.filename, file.file)}, ...)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you send the same file a few times then you may need to move pointer to the beginning of file after sending

```
file.file.seek(0)
```

or

```
await file.seek(0)
```

---

Full working code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, UploadFile, File
import httpx

app = FastAPI()
client = httpx.AsyncClient()


@app.post("/endpoint/")
async def foo(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print('/endpoint/')
    
    urls = ["/some/other/endpoint/", "/another/endpoint/"]
    
    results = []
    
    for url in urls:
        response = await client.post('http://localhost:8000' + url, files={'file': (file.filename, file.file)})
        #file.file.seek(0)  # move back at the beginning of file after sending to other URL
        await file.seek(0)  # move back at the beginning of file after sending to other URL
        results.append(response)
        
    results = [item.text for item in results]
    
    print('results:', results)
    
    return {"bar": "baz"}


@app.post("/some/other/endpoint/")
async def baz(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print('/some/other/endpoint/')
    
    print('filename:', file.filename)
    print('content_type:', file.content_type)
    
    # Do something with the file object
    
    return {"file": file.filename}


@app.post("/another/endpoint/")
async def baz(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)): 
    print('/another/endpoint/')
    
    print('filename:', file.filename)
    print('content_type:', file.content_type)
    
    # Do something with the file object
    
    return {"file": file.content_type}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it saved my week. I was not finding anything useful and the question & answer are from yesterday (LOL). Thanks both!!